# Read committed и блокировки записи

Tags: база-данных

Английская википедия дает следующую формулировку read committed

> In this isolation level, a lock-based concurrency control DBMS implementation keeps write locks (acquired on selected data) until the end of the transaction, but read locks are released as soon as the SELECT operation is performed

Я не до конца понимаю, почему выносится требование удерживать блокировки на уровне изоляции, который допускает чтение измененных данных. Насколько понимаю, база данных не может писать незакоммиченные данные прямо поверх существующих просто физически, потому что иначе откат транзакции невозможен, и ей так или иначе нужна staging area / wal, поэтому вариант с необходимостью держать эти локи, чтобы никто не увидел незакомиченные данные, мне тоже кажется неверным. Почему же все-таки этот уровень изоляции требует удерживание блокировок записи? Потому что иначе это противоречит атомарности транзакции?

Comment: @Sergey вопрос не про детали имплементации

Comment: @Sergey я не считаю эти требования невыполнимыми. Мне кажется, вы отвечаете немного не на тот вопрос.

Comment: Господи, да при чем здесь это все?